# "How much is its cost" vs "How much does it cost"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, possessives

When buying something, what it more suitable to ask the seller?

> 1. How much **does** it cost?
> 2. How much is **its** cost?

I know that the word "cost" is a verb and noun as well, but my question is what is the acceptable way - if there is.

Comment: 1. is correct. If you want to use *cost* as a noun, you don't ask *how?* but *what?* -- "What is its cost?". But that is very formal and stiff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.   I would have to say that both are acceptable.

However, the questions "How much does it cost?" and "What does it cost?" are very common in my dialect.   The question "How much is its cost?" sounds formal, foreign, or oddly emphatic.

My dialect is American, so feel free to ignore me if you prefer to emulate some other dialect.